# An example of an infinite artinian serial ring $R$ with $J^2(R)=0$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

A module $M_R$ is called **uniserial** if the set of all of its submodules is a chain with respect to the inclusion (e.g., the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$, for every positive integer $m$, are uniserial). $M_R$ is called **serial** if it is the direct sum of uniserial modules. Indeed, an indecomposable module is serial if and only if it is uniserial. A ring $R$ is called **right** (resp. **left**) **uniserial** if the module $R_R$ (resp. ${}_RR$) is uniserial, and $R$ is **right** (resp. **left**) serial if the module $R_R$ (resp. ${}_RR$) is serial. A ring $R$ is **serial** if it is both left and right serial. For instance, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for every $n > 1$ is serial.

An example of a finite artinian (left and right artinian) serial ring $R$ with $J^2=J^2(R)=0$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ where $p,q$ are positive primes (not necessarily distinct).

I wonder if there exists an example of an infinite artinian serial ring with $J^2=0$ which is not semisimple?!. I appreciate if the details of the example are included.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$? It's infinite, Artinian, uniserial, and has a nonzero radical $(x+(x^2))$ squaring to zero.

Or $T_2(\mathbb R)$ (upper triangular matrices), whose radical is $\begin{bmatrix}0&\mathbb R \\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$ squaring to zero.

You didn't specify if $J(R)$ had to be nonzero, and in that case any semisimple ring would work.

Comment: Here's the [DaRT query for candidates with nonzero radical](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=63l&H=63r&H=77l&H=77r&L=43&L=6). Of course, the results had to be inspected to see if they had (or could be made to have) a radical squaring to zero.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I really need $R$ to be not semisimple. I edited the question. Does still $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ work ?!.
What is the ring $T_2(\mathbb{R})$ ?!.

Comment: @HusseinEid Both examples I gave are not semisimple...  As I mentioned, $J(R)\neq \{0\}$ in both cases.